# Is Simplify 3D really worth it?

Tags: simplify3d, support-structures

I've heard alot about simplify 3D recently. It sounds like it's a great software, but 150 dollars!? The only thing that seems too different from other slicers is the placable supports, but Z suite has that now as well. Cura must be coming out with placable supports soon if they're going to stay in the game. It does also have dual extrusion, but so does just about every other free slicer out there. I just don't understand what makes it worth 150 US dollars.

Comment: There's a 2 week refund period, in case you buy it but end up not liking it.

Comment: I know it's opinion based but I'm going to answer anyways because I asked myself that same question before I purchased it. Simplify can be used in Remote Desktop sessions; Cura cannot. Cura's 3d rendering engine prevents it from even launching. Simplify uses all your cpu cores to slice, most others don't. Simplify documents it's g-code with the settings used to generate it. Most others don't. Simplify allows for different post processing options (e.g. infill) for different objects on the bed; most don't. Simplify allows you to see the effect of velocity painting; most don't. This includes Cura

Answer (score 2):

The free slicers are catching up with Simplify3D, and are even overtaking it in some areas, so purchasing it may not make much sense to hobbyists. However, for professional print shops, where printers may cost twenty times as much (or even more), 150 dollars is nothing (especially since it is 150 dollars per PC, not 150 dollars per printer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, simplify 3D has more than only placeable supports and I'm very happy with it. I Made my 3D printers and I had headaches with free slicers due I had to review the final result on pronterface, of course this programs was unable to run perfectly on P4 PC's with XP.

When I started to change for other programs I recurr to use Cura, getting a nice prints but I had problems with Z offsets and a lot of burrs or "spider threads".

Then I could get simplify 3D, since the first printing I never changed again to other slicers and even Cura. I have set multiple setting for diferent filament types according their better flow temperature and printer type since I use the same program in one PC for 3 printers and planing to get 2 aditional printers.

Printers are almost free, software not.